# Can we use Azure AD with Keycloak and Kong?

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak, kong

What i want is keycloak with Azure AD integration connect with my kong so that i can use this authentication with my frontend(react) and backedn(java) .
I have no idea how can i do this or is this even possible!

Thanks!

I have checked the docs but didnt get much with Azure AD integrated with Keycloak and kong both

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add Azure AD as IDP in Keycloak. This integrates fine with Kong, APISIX, and other API gateways.

Here is a tutorial: https://www.hcl-software.com/blog/versionvault/how-to-configure-microsoft-azure-active-directory-as-keycloak-identity-provider-to-enable-single-sign-on-for-hcl-compass